# How to handle selecting dynamic properties from database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have designed a little database the idea is that I have a table products and each product  has its category and dynamic list of properties (those properties are in another table):

```
ProductCategories{ProductCategoryId, Name}
Products{ProductId, Name, ProductCategoryId}
```

I bind product for some category here. Now, each ProductCategory is related to another table where I can add properties for that category:

```
CategoryProperties{CategoryPropertyId, ProductCategoryId, Name}
```

Values for each property is in this table:

```
ProductPropertyValues{ProductId, CategoryPropertyId, Value}
```

The problem is when I execute query:

```
select p.Name as ProductName, m.Name as Manufacturer, pc.Name as Category
from products p
left join dbo.Manufacturers m
on p.ManufactureId = m.ManufactureId
left join dbo.ProductCategories pc
on p.ProductCategoryId = pc.ProductCategoryId
```

This gives me result like:

```
| some product name | RedBull | Can |
```

But I want to get and **all related properties** for this **product category** and that is the problem. When I try this query:

```
select p.Name as ProductName, m.Name as Manufacturer, pc.Name as Category, cp.Name,  ppv.Value
from products p
left join dbo.Manufacturers m
on p.ManufactureId = m.ManufactureId
left join dbo.ProductCategories pc
on p.ProductCategoryId = pc.ProductCategoryId

left join dbo.CategoryProperties cp
on pc.ProductCategoryId = cp.ProductCategoryId

left join dbo.ProductPropertyValues ppv
on p.ProductId = ppv.ProductId
```

After this query **instead of one row** in result I get **'121'** results.
I don't know what am I doing wrong.
I want to get result like:

```
| Product name      | Manufacturer | Category | prop1 | prop2     | prop3| Prop4          |      
| some product name | RedBull      | Can      | 34    | something | 45.6 | something else |
```

What am I doing wrong or this is impossible?
I get some cross join here as I understand it.
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are attempting to `PIVOT` the data.  This will take you row values and convert it into columns.

If you have a set number of properties to convert, then you can hard-code the query into something similar to this:

```
select *
from
(
  select p.Name as ProductName, 
    m.Name as Manufacturer, 
    pc.Name as Category, 
    cp.Name,
    ppv.Value
  from products p
  left join dbo.Manufacturers m
    on p.ManufactureId = m.ManufactureId
  left join dbo.ProductCategories pc
    on p.ProductCategoryId = pc.ProductCategoryId
  left join dbo.CategoryProperties cp
    on pc.ProductCategoryId = cp.ProductCategoryId
  left join dbo.ProductPropertyValues ppv
    on p.ProductId = ppv.ProductId
    and cp.CategoryPropertyId = ppv.CategoryPropertyId
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for Name in ([Code], [Data], etc)
) piv
```

It gets a little more difficult, if you have an unknown number of values.  You will have to use dynamic sql to perform this.  I showed you a static version because it is easier to move from a hard-coded version to the dynamic solution.

The key to the dynamic version is getting the column names.  The full script will be similar to this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(name) 
                    from dbo.CategoryProperties
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ProductName, Manufacturer, Category,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select p.Name as ProductName, 
                  m.Name as Manufacturer, 
                  pc.Name as Category, 
                  cp.Name,  
                  ppv.Value
                from products p
                left join dbo.Manufacturers m
                  on p.ManufactureId = m.ManufactureId
                left join dbo.ProductCategories pc
                  on p.ProductCategoryId = pc.ProductCategoryId
                left join dbo.CategoryProperties cp
                  on pc.ProductCategoryId = cp.ProductCategoryId
                left join dbo.ProductPropertyValues ppv
                  on p.ProductId = ppv.ProductId
                  and cp.CategoryPropertyId = ppv.CategoryPropertyId
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for Name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: Does this mean's that each property name must have `Prop_` prefix?

Comment: @1110 No, I am creating the columns with the name `Prop_` and then appending to the end of it a row number value for each one.  So if you have 5 properties, then you will have columns named `Prop_1`, `Prop_2`, etc.  I have created a [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5df4) with your table structures, can you add some insert statements with for some sample data and then post the new created schema link in a comment?  It would be easier to show this with your data.

Comment: In dynamic query I get `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'.: ` fot this line `) t
    on p.ProductId`

Comment: I tried it now. But I am not getting good result. I get 11 rows but all properties has same value :( I have updated question with image of my result.

Comment: @1110 see my edit.  You need to convert the `cp.Name` values into columns.  I have updated my script.

Comment: We are so close to solution. I get property names with this script but values are still just one same. I added image to the question of the result.

Comment: @1110 Can you post some sample data for each table?  Or edit the sql fiddle -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5df4?

Comment: @1110 See my edit, I think you need to change your join to the `ProductPropertyValues` table to include a join to two tables.

Comment: That last edit gives me error `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Invalid column name 'CategoryProductId'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Invalid column name 'CategoryProductId'.`

Comment: Yeee... super mega :) that worked. The only problem now is that I have to study this code to understand it :) but that's my problem. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about the cross-join, I think the problem is that you are not tying `ProductPropertyValues` back to `CategoryProperties`.  Therefore you get all the properties from `ProductPropertyValues` for all categories for each `CategoryProperties` row.

Now, as far as getting the format you want ... that's called "pivoted", because you want to take a vertical list (all the properties) and "pivot" it, rendering it horizontally.  That is tough to do dynamically, because, while SQL Server does have a  `PIVOT` command, it requires that you know all the values that you mean to use for column names at coding time.  While that would work if you knew your properties were called "Prop 1", "Prop 2", etc., I assume the names vary with the product.

How determined are you to get all the properties in one row?  It can be done, but it's going to be complicated.

Comment: You were right about cross join. I changed query now and it returns me 11 rows. That's exactly how much properties for that category I have. That part is fixed but I really need it in one row. I am struggling with this whole day :(

Comment: @1110 Do you have a maximum number of properties you want to display? Or just "however many there are"?

Comment: All properties. So the second.

Comment: @1110  I was going to link you to a previous post by bluefeet, above, but it looks like he's given you the same answer, customized for your case.  I might have done it a little differently but the idea would have been the same.